# Fully Qualified Domain Name in SMTPClient

Tags: smtpclient

In our application we use [SmtpClient component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to send emails. The problem is after upgrade our smtp server requires fully qualified domain name in HELO command.

Currently our IT somehow created workaround for this, but this is temporary, I really want to comply with their requirement. I could not find how to set it up though. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Similar question [FQDN with SmtpClient in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37410598)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work. Had to use "mailSettings" in config files under

More here: http://discoveringdotnet.alexeyev.org/2014/04/fqdn-for-smtpclient.html