# FQDN with SmtpClient in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, smtp

I am using the .Net class `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` in Powershell to send a mail with some attached documents. It all works great in our test environment, but fails in production.

The problem is, that a fully specified domain name is required in production to send the mails. However the SmtpClient does not allow me to specify this, as far as I know. I've read online, that you can use web.config settings with asp.net to specify the domain name, but I don't seem to be able to use it with Powershell.

Is there a way around this or do I have to implement it in another language?

**Edit:** This is the code I'm using

```
$SmtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient "mail.mailserver.com", 25
$Mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

# Custom (working) Cmdlet for creating a NetworkCredential object
$SmtpClient.Credentials = (GetCredential-FromFile)

$Mail.Subject = "New Import"
$Mail.Body = ""
$Mail.From = "myaddress@mailserver.com"
$Mail.To.Add("myaddress@mailserver.com")
$Mail.Attachments.Add(New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment "file.txt")

$SmtpClient.Send($Mail)
```

The SMTP-Server is set, but I need to set the FQDN of the client (the machine using the script).

Comment: "However the SmtpClient does not allow me to specify this, as far as I know" - eh what? How did you get that impression? Have you tried?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I've read the class documentation [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and I couldn't find a method or property to set the FQDN

Comment: [***host** \[...\] A String that contains the name \[...\] of the host computer \[...\]*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0y6s613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). "Name" does not mean just single label names.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I used the constructor with host and port, but this only sets the host name of the smtp server, not the client

Comment: What would you need the client's hostname for?

Comment: `Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Command parameter not implemented. The server response was: 5.5.2 <not-smtp-server>: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname"`
apparently I need to specify my client's fully-qualified hostname

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug (or missing feature, depending on how you want to look at it) in the .NET Framework implementation. By default the NetBIOS name of the host is used in the HELO command, and the `SmtpClient` class doesn't have a property for configuring the HELO hostname in the program/script. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77f45c5f-76be-400c-a529-a1e49d6d8e62/systemnetmailsmtpclient-fqdn-required?forum=netfxnetcom) for a detailed discussion of the problem. You need to create/change a configuration file on the client to override the default.

Edit the file `powershell.exe.config` in the same directory where `powershell.exe` is located. Create the file if it doesn't exist. Make sure it contains at least the following lines:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
        <network clientDomain="mail.example.com" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Replace `mail.example.com` with your client's FQDN.

For .NET Framework 2.0 you first need to apply a [patch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957497) (or upgrade to .NET Framework 4.0 or newer) before you can configure the `clientDomain` attribute.

For more information on SMTP client network settings see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164242.aspx).

Had you posted your code and error message right from the start we would've been able to provide this answer much earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a restriction for creating the `powershell.exe.config`? I can't run powershell after creating the file. It says, because a file's size changed, powershell cannot be run anymore

Comment: You need admin privileges to create/edit the file, of course. Other than that it worked fine when I tested it here. You have Software Restriction Policies or something in place?